Access child component from dynamically created component - Angular 12
Inside global-component I have method for dynamically creating component
const comFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ParentComponent);
const component: any = this.componentContainer.createComponent(comFactory);

(where componentContainer is ViewContainerRef)
Inside my parent-component I have child-component (which has two more child components inside):
<child-component #childCmp></child-component>

Is there any way I can access child-component from my global component?

The code explanation is given below, but for latest angular version there is a lot of code that uses deprecated method, so this is the latest way of achieving the same.
import {
  Component,
  ComponentRef,
  createComponent,
  QueryList,
  ViewChildren,
  Injector,
  EnvironmentInjector,
  ApplicationRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        child
      `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        <app-child/>
        <app-child/>
      `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childs!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
        <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
          Learn more about Angular
        </a>
      `,
})
export class App {
  component: ComponentRef<ParentComponent>;

  constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: EnvironmentInjector
  ) {
    this.component = createComponent(ParentComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
    });
    document.body.appendChild(this.component.location.nativeElement);
    this.appRef.attachView(this.component.hostView);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const childViewChildren: QueryList<ChildComponent> =
      this.component.instance.childs;
    console.log(childViewChildren);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
Getting to Know the createComponent API in Angular - Netanel Basal

You can take a viewChildren of the child component, inside the parent.
...
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childs: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  ...
}

Then in the global component declare the component initialization inside the constructor. So that the child elements are available in the ngAfterViewInit hook call.
export class App {
  component: ComponentRef<ParentComponent>;
  
  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private componentContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    const comFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ParentComponent);
    this.component = this.componentContainer.createComponent(comFactory);
  }

Also note that I am storing the component reference as a class property so that it can be access on ngAfterViewInit. So when we access the children it will be accessible.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const childViewChildren: QueryList<ChildComponent> =
      this.component.instance.childs;
  }

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactory,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  QueryList,
  ViewChildren,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    child
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <app-child/>
    <app-child/>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childs!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  component: ComponentRef<ParentComponent>;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private componentContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    const comFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ParentComponent);
    this.component = this.componentContainer.createComponent(comFactory);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const childViewChildren: QueryList<ChildComponent> =
      this.component.instance.childs;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Forgot to mention, I'm using Angular 12 and EnvironmentInjector is not available

@Sara I have provided code for old and new angular, try the bottom approach in my answer
